# ! LaTeX Error: Undefined color `BLACK'

Tags: errors, color

i have written all the text in black color, but i get this error several times in the same page:

```
! LaTeX Error: Undefined color `BLACK'.
```

i tried to solve it by writting this: `\definecolor{black}{gray}{0,0,0}` but it didn´t work.

what should i do?

Comment: Are you using this in a sectional title (perhaps a chapter/section heading)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you actually write `BLACK` in capital letters in your document?

Comment: following @MaxD, did you (in particular) type `\color{BLACK}` anywhere.  if so, try using the word in lower-case.

Comment: load the package `xcolor` in your preamble and write `\definecolor{BLACK}{named}{black}` below that. This should define your `BLACK` colour somewhere in your code as the normal `black` you would suspect. Like this you can use `BLACK` everywhere and change it's grayscale or whatever later on. This is my preferred way to handle colours.

Comment: If you've written *all* your text in black, I'm not sure why you need to specify this at all. Black is the default. Obviously if you changed to some other colour, you'd need `black` to change back. But if the text is all in black, you shouldn't need to do anything. What am I missing here?

Comment: MaxD: i did it with capital letters and lower case.

Comment: i tried with xcolor package and \definecolor{BLACK}{named}{black} but didnt work.

Comment: in the complete log i get this:  LaTeX Error: Undefined color `BLACK'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.440 como el etanol y la urea. }{\Large \par
                                             }
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Comment: @Emi: without providing more details, it is very difficult to understand what's going on there and provide you concrete help.

Comment: Why don't you write everywhere black with small letters?

Answer (score 15):

Very likely the color setting is inside a section (or friend) title and the title goes into the header with uppercase letters. `\MakeUppercase` (or `\uppercase`) does not know the semantics of arguments, it just converts all letters to uppercase: `\textcolor{black}{hello}` becomes `\textcolor{BLACK}{HELLO}`.

Workarounds:

- Providing a definition for the uppercase color name:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \colorlet{BLACK}{black}
  \pagestyle{headings}
  \begin{document}
  \section{\textcolor{black}{Hello}}
  \end{document}
  ```
- Using a command to hide the string "black":

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{color}
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\textblack}{\textcolor{black}}
  \pagestyle{headings}
  \begin{document}
  \section{\textblack{Hello}}
  \end{document}
  ```

  `\DeclareRobustCommand` protects `\textblack` from expanding inside `\MakeUppercase` to dispose and uppercase "black" in `\textcolor{black}` again.

BTW: `\definecolor{black}{gray}{0,0,0}` is not correct, because color model `gray` only expects one number: `\definecolor{black}{gray}{0}`.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot! i selected all the document and did "text style - color: reset"

Comment: Absolutely clever! I had the same problem, but with color 'BLUE'... thanks!